# create dynamic Object (as function(...))

Tags: javascript, function, object, dynamic

I create an object with dynamic properties during runtime in JavaScript.

It simply works like that:

```
var object = {
    'time' = ""
};
```

After that, I'm able to add more properties, for instance, like that:

```
var propName = "value1";
object[propName] = "some content...";
```

But I need to work with a real object, so that I can create a new instance, e.g.:
var myObject = NewObject('myTime', 'myValue1', 'myValue2' ...);

For creating a static custom object I would do this:

```
function NewObject(time, val1, val2, ... valn) {
    this.time = time;
    this.val1 = val1;
    ...
}
```

But I have no idea, how to design such a function dynamically, depending on different user input my NewObject could have 1 to n value properties...?

I know, I would be better to implement a List or Array, but I would like to know, if there's a solution for my problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you create an array within your `NewObject`? For example, `this.vals = array(); 
for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
this.vals[i] = arguments[i];
}`

Comment: How about cloning an object, as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: thanks for your hints. I 'var newInstance = jQuery.extend({}, object);' worked in my case. But I will try @Passerby 's solution, because the jQuery.extend function might not work in every browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arguments` object inside function:

```
function NewObject(time){
    this.time=time;
    if(arguments.length>1){
        for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
            this["val"+i]=arguments[i];
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQZAG/)